# Boost Asio Error

Tags: c++, boost, windows-7, boost-asio

I've tried to see if anyone else if having this problem, but I haven't found anything online yet. Does anything in this code looks like I'm invoking boost incorrectly?

This code works when I am logged into the machine that is starting the TCP server, but fails when no one is logged in. I stripped the code down to only look at the boost asio logic.

```
//create _acceptor, which will eventually listen for incomming connections, asynchronously
_acceptor = boost::shared_ptr<tcp::acceptor>(new tcp::acceptor(*_io_service));
_acceptor->open(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), _port).protocol());
_acceptor->set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(false));

//omitted logic find a port that is open
_acceptor->bind(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), _port));

//omitted error handling logic if open port not found

//Start listening for incoming connections asynchronously.
_acceptor->listen();

sslSocketPtr ssl_socket(sslSocketPtr(new ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket>(*_io_service, _sslContext)));
_acceptor->async_accept(ssl_socket->lowest_layer(),
    boost::bind(&TCPServer::handle_sslAccept, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, ssl_socket));
```

When no one is logged into the machine, the ssl_socket constructor throws the exception: "static_mutex: Access is denied".

If I define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SSL the code works correctly, but I think that may be contributing to another bug in my code. So I am trying to use the latest SSL logic from Boost.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "when no one is logged into the machine" do you start the process in a different way? Also, what platform are you running this on (I can't believe you didn't mention this essential bit of information in the post...)

Comment: Sorry for not including the scenario and environment. This is running on Windows 7. The process is launched from a remote machine connecting to a daemon which launches another program as the remote user (with their credentials). This final program is the one having an issue with the TCP Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume from the symptoms that you run on Windows.

On windows, static_mutex is implemented as a named (interprocess) mutex and gets "opened" using **[`CreateMutexW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx)**:

> If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, GetLastError returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, `bInitialOwner` is ignored, and the calling thread is not granted ownership. However, **if the caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`** and the caller should use the `OpenMutex` function.

As you can see you don't have the required permissions. However, you could still have this working if the mutex is always created by a privileged process. In that case you could modify the code that opens an existing named mutex with `OpenMutex` as the documentation hints.

It's likely easier to run the process under a user that has the required permissions thought

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable explanation. This seems like it would be a bug in Boost since I do not call CreateMutex or OpenMutex directly. Would you agree with that?

Comment: @Snowman6286 I would not agree with that. The fact that the library implements features that require permissions is not - per se - a bug. You could ask the library devs though, they will be able to have a more authoritative answer